# Can I use BufferedImage in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I need to use Buffered Image into android.So I used java.awt.image.BufferedImage class jar.but it Shows`java.lang.noClassDefFoundError`.anybody can i use BufferedImage into android?if yes,can tell what jar i should use?

Answer (score 1):

java.awt library is not supported by android,

if you need to do image manipulations you can use BitmapFactory and Bitmap classes, they are native android code

but you have not stated what exactly you need to do